# Prevent the animation of :after and :before elements in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to animate a HTML element which has an :after element. While animating, the :after is also getting animated. Is there any ways to prevent the animation of the :after or :before element?

Example:

HTML:

```
<div class="animate"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.animate{
     position: relative;
     animation: zoom 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.animate:after{
     content: " ";
     position: absolute;
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     background: green;
}
@keyframes zoom {
     0%{
        transform: scale(0);
     }
     50%{
        transform: scale(1.5);
     }
     100%{
        transform: scale(0);
     }
```

Comment: No because the pseudo-element is part of the originating element. It doesn't make sense to animate an element without animating whatever's inside it.

Comment: But, I can animate the :after element without affecting the <div> tag.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPdEpR